# Configure back to normal wifi station after access point mode (hostapd)

Tags: hostapd, wpa-supplicant

I have set up access point according to the manual https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md on respberry pi 4b.

It works fine. Now I need to disable AP and connect my Rpi to a router.

This is a short log of what I do: stop hostapd and restart wpa_supplicant and networking

```
pi@kyb-pi4 ~> sudo systemctl stop hostapd
pi@kyb-pi4 ~> pgrep -af wpa_supplicant
3361 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
pi@kyb-pi4 ~> pgrep -af hostapd
pi@kyb-pi4 ~> sudo systemctl restart wpa_supplicant
pi@kyb-pi4 ~> sudo systemctl restart networking
pi@kyb-pi4 ~> pgrep -af wpa_supplicant
3443 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
pi@kyb-pi4 ~> tail -f /var/log/syslog&
Oct 22 18:54:43 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
Oct 22 18:54:43 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
Oct 22 18:54:43 kyb-pi4 wpa_supplicant[3443]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Oct 22 18:54:49 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: Stopping Raise network interfaces...
Oct 22 18:54:49 kyb-pi4 ifdown[3477]: ifdown: /etc/network/interfaces.d/wifi-kybs-route:1: misplaced option
Oct 22 18:54:49 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: networking.service: Succeeded.
Oct 22 18:54:49 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: Stopped Raise network interfaces.
Oct 22 18:54:49 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Oct 22 18:54:49 kyb-pi4 ifup[3492]: ifup: /etc/network/interfaces.d/wifi-kybs-route:1: misplaced option
Oct 22 18:54:49 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
pi@kyb-pi4 ~>
pi@kyb-pi4 ~>
pi@kyb-pi4 ~> sudo systemctl restart networking
Oct 22 18:55:17 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: Stopping Raise network interfaces...
Oct 22 18:55:17 kyb-pi4 ifdown[3573]: ifdown: /etc/network/interfaces.d/wifi-kybs-route:1: misplaced option
Oct 22 18:55:17 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: networking.service: Succeeded.
Oct 22 18:55:17 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: Stopped Raise network interfaces.
Oct 22 18:55:17 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Oct 22 18:55:17 kyb-pi4 ifup[3588]: ifup: /etc/network/interfaces.d/wifi-kybs-route:1: misplaced option
Oct 22 18:55:17 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
pi@kyb-pi4 ~> sudo systemctl restart wpa_supplicant
Oct 22 18:55:25 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: Stopping WPA supplicant...
Oct 22 18:55:25 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: wpa_supplicant.service: Succeeded.
Oct 22 18:55:25 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: Stopped WPA supplicant.
Oct 22 18:55:25 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
Oct 22 18:55:25 kyb-pi4 systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
Oct 22 18:55:25 kyb-pi4 wpa_supplicant[3638]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
pi@kyb-pi4 ~> ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.144.23  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 192.168.255.255
        inet6 fe80::b01e:b82b:6de0:acb6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:12:87:92  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10533  bytes 2106720 (2.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8943  bytes 1099980 (1.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1700  bytes 115208 (112.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1700  bytes 115208 (112.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

As you can see wlan0 does looks down

```
pi@kyb-pi4 ~> ifconfig wlan0 up
pi@kyb-pi4 ~> ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 9c:43:1e:49:c0:85  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12  bytes 1656 (1.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But it has no IP assigned. It does not want to connect to my AP. But it worked before I configured hostapd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear exactly what you ACTUALLY did, but any services you `enable` you should `disable` - including `dnsmasq`.

Raspberry Pi OS **DOES NOT** use Debian networking (by default) it uses `dhcpcd`

`systemctl restart networking` is not needed (but probably does no harm - unless you are relying on `/etc/network/interfaces`)

You should **NOT** `systemctl restart wpa_supplicant` this should be started by `dhcpcd`.

The file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` should contain something like the following:-

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=AU

network={
    ssid="ESSID"
    psk="Your_wifi_password"
}
```

You probably edited `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to set a static IP address, so you should remove this.

You should check `systemctl status dhcpcd`

Rather than undoing things, it would be easier to restore from your backup.
The fragments you have listed are inconclusive.

Comment: You told me main idea: wpa_supplicant is run by dhcpcd! and I found what to do. Thank you.